# CMake fails at command line but can manually build makefile

Tags: cmake, makefile, cmake-gui, lynxos

I am attemping to use CMake to configure/build for a very old version of LynxOS (2.2.2) and have gotten to the point where it is generating a makefile however I am getting the following error when running cmake:

```
cmake --debug-trycompile -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=path/to/los/gcc.exe -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/toolchain/los_tc.cmake .
```

gives me:

```
Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe -E env VERBOSE=1  -f Makefile cmTC_2e53c/fast && The parameter is incorrect
```

However, if I navigate to ./CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-cwzvwo and run **make -f Makefile all** then the makefile will build fine with no errors.

My toolchain file is very simple, note that this is on windows, **I've shortened the paths in this example to hide them but they are correct in the real version.**

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME los222)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR ppc)
set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING 1)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /path/to/gcc.exe)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /path/to/cdk/win32-xcoff-ppc;/path/to/cdk/win32-xcoff-ppc/usr/bin)

set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM /path/to/make.exe)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

I am not sure why the cmake.exe is trying to run the Makefile and giving me the error, when I can run it fine on command line myself.

**Update:**
I have gotten it to finish generating by just adding:

> **set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED 1) set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_FORCED 1)**

since it is generating the makefile correctly, dunno if this is a great way to do things but at least it gets past that step.

So now, when I do a **cmake --build .** I get a similar error:

```
The parameter is incorrect
```

CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was:  -f Makefile &&

Running the makefile manually I get:

```
gcc: cannot specify -o with -c or -S and multiple compilations
```

I've tracked this down into my build.make file, the error is in here:

```
CMakeFiles/fdm.dir/main.c.obj: CMakeFiles/fdm.dir/compiler_depend.ts
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --progress-dir=C:/project_files/_CMAKE/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_1) "Building C object CMakeFiles/fdm.dir/main.c.obj"
    C:/RW_APPS/LW/2.2.2/ppc_dev/cdk/win32-xcoff-ppc/usr/bin/gcc.exe $(C_DEFINES) $(C_INCLUDES) $(C_FLAGS) -MD -MT CMakeFiles/fdm.dir/main.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles/fdm.dir/main.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/fdm.dir/main.c.obj -c C:/project_files/_CMAKE/main.c
```

Which I can get working by removing the **CMakeFiles/fdm.dir/main.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles/fdm.dir/main.c.obj.d** section.  Is there a way to specify what is put here in cmake?

Comment: The line with `The parameter is incorrect` is not the error message. It is just the line which is executed. So, what exact error message CMake gives you?

Comment: `cmake.exe -E env VERBOSE=1  -f Makefile cmTC_2e53c/fast &&` looks wrong. I would have expected to see `cmake.exe -E env VERBOSE=1 -- make -f Makefile cmTC_2e53c/fast &&`

Comment: I assume your line `set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM /path/to/make.exe)` is not literally like that. Please show what you actually have there. I suspect you set it wrong, and actually set it to be an empty string somehow.

Comment: And by the way, if that path is something specific to your machine (which I'll bet it is), I'd recommend to set it in a presets file instead of hardcoding it into your CMakeLists.txt. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/75143040/11107541.

Comment: Are you trying to build on Windows?  If not I don't understand why your CMake path is `C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe` I would try to track that down: it can't be right.

Comment: Yes this is windows, that path is correct.  Also the other paths are correct, Ive shortened them in the example to not show where my install is.

Comment: "_Make command was: -f Makefile &&_" This is **still / also** a symptom of the `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` problem I mentioned earlier. **please show us what you you actually put in `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM`. Why didn't you address my comment?**